# Write Excel values in to the attribute table of a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python-script-tool

I am using QGIS version 2.18.19. I have written a standalone script which converts a DXF file in to polygon shapefile. Now I want to write data into the attribute table of the polygon shapefile from a Excel file which I used as a input to the script.

My code is as follows:

```
dxf_to_polygon=name
t=table
dxffile=file
fpoly=output vector
outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.in.dxf', dxffile,'1',True,False,True,False,False,True,'200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000',0,None)
outputs_GRASS7V_CLEAN_1=processing.runalg('grass7:v.clean', outputs_GRASS7V_IN_DXF_1['output'],1,0.1,'200000.000000,700000.000000,200000.000000,700000.000000',-1.0,0.0001,None,None)
outputs_QGISPOLYGONIZE_1=processing.runalg('qgis:polygonize', outputs_GRASS7V_CLEAN_1['output'],True,True,None)
outputs_SAGAPOLYGONDISSOLVEBYATTRIBUTE_1=processing.runalg('saga:polygondissolvebyattribute', outputs_QGISPOLYGONIZE_1['OUTPUT'],'area','layer','perimeter',False,None)
outputs_SAGAPOLYGONDISSOLVEALLPOLYGONS_1=processing.runalg('saga:polygondissolveallpolygons', outputs_SAGAPOLYGONDISSOLVEBYATTRIBUTE_1['DISSOLVED'],False,None)
outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_1=processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', outputs_SAGAPOLYGONDISSOLVEALLPOLYGONS_1['DISSOLVED'],'Req_No',2,30.0,0.0,None)
outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_2=processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_1['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'Surveyor_Name',2,25.0,0.0,None)
outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_3=processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_2['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'Survey_Date',2,20.0,0.0,None)
outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_4=processing.runalg('qgis:addfieldtoattributestable', outputs_QGISADDFIELDTOATTRIBUTESTABLE_3['OUTPUT_LAYER'],'Plan_Name',2,20.0,0.0,fpoly)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If both the shape file and Excel file have some column which can be used to identify the items then you can use Join feature in QGIS as you can also load the Excel file to QGIS. But I cannot help you with python...

Comment: i want to read excel values and write the same to attribute table.anyway thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: You can do that by joining them like @Juhele is telling you. Add a field to the shapefile, join the tables, calculate the field, remove join.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question. You should [edit] the question to provide clarification. Please take the [Tour] to better understand your role in curating a question.

Comment: @ShankaHerath - You could use the processing tool `Join attributes table` which should let you join the table of the final output with the excel input.

Comment: problem is, in my attribute table consist of one row and 5 columns.but in my excel sheet is having, 2 columns and 7 rows.So once i join excel sheet, i can't see the excel values in the joined table